# Browse server is not working in CKeditor with CKFinder

Tags: php, ckfinder

After integrate ckeditor with ckfinder I can not browse files. I can upload files.

After click browse:
Error: `The requested URL /php/public/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.php was not found on this server.`

configuration

I just did that

**js file**

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('about_editor'); 
 CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor );
```

**config.php**

```
$config['authentication'] = function () {
    return true;
};

'baseUrl'      => 'http://localhost/php/public/files/ckfinder/userfiles/',
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution `.htaccess RewriteEngine off`